# authenticate user using docusign

Tags: php, docusignapi

I have 2 types of users in my system , lets say its A and B. A has an account with docusign and sends a document through email to B. B (who does not have an account on docusign) signs it using docusign. Now for making the api call (https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information), i need to specify the integrator key, email and password.

My question is how will i check whether a user has an docusign account or not and if he/she has an account, should i store the credentials of that user in the db or is there any way by which i can create a new docusign  user automatically during  the registration process?

Edit : i am using rest api with php

Comment: I'm a little confused on exactly what you're asking, but have provided a starting answer...

Answer (score 0):

With DocuSign you only need an account to **SEND** documents, signing documents is always free and you do **not** need an account to sign.